# How to set HSM Provider in my CSR

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, csr, hsm

I have a key pair in my hsm and I want to generate CSR from it. I use Open SSL and these code . when CSR is generated, It does not have hsm provider. how to set hsm provider in my csr?

```
 openssl_conf = openssl_def
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section
[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = enginepkcs11
MODULE_PATH =  cs2_pkcs11
PIN = 123456
init = 0
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn
[ dn ]
```

my question is edited. I explain .inf file in comment.

```
[NewRequest]
Subject=""
Exportable=True
KeyLength=..
keyUsage=..
UserProtected=FALSE
MachineKeySet=..
ProviderName="...CSP provider..."
UseExistingKeySet=..
RequestType=..
```

Comment: I edited my question.. when I create .inf file. and use certreq command in windows. I can set Providername, after csr is generated , providername filed is in csr as attribute. cert req command can find storage with providername but when I use Pkcs#11 in my question ,Storage is found with dll address and I can not sure key pairs in hsm or not.

Answer (score 0):

A CSR (PKCS#10) cannot have provider information. A CSR is basically your public key + your data like (Subject DN) + signature algorithm, combined in a specific format, and signed by your private key.

More info about PKCS#10 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986#page-5).

Answer (score 0):

Attributes for a CSR have to be specified in the openssl configuration file used. According to [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/req) you can specify an *attribute* section.